# Using WSL bash from within python

Tags: python, windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using windows 10 and while working on a new project, I need to interact with WSL(Ubuntu on windows) bash from within python (windows python interpreter).

I tried using subprocess python library to execute commands.. what I did looks like this:

```py
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_call(['cmd','ubuntu1804', 'BashCmdHere(eg: ls)']))#not working

print(subprocess.check_output("ubuntu1804", shell=True).decode())#also not working
```

The expected behavior is to execute ubuntu1804 command which starts a wsl linux bash on which I want to execute my 'BashCmdHere' and retrieve its results to python but **it just freezes**. What am I doing wrong ? or how to do this ?

Thank you so much

Comment: I believe once you have WSL installed you can execute bash commands from the normal cmd window by prepending the command `bash`.  With this approach you will not need to launch WSL just leverage the normal cmd

Comment: from a cmd or PowerShell command prompt everything works fine .. but when I try to invoke ubuntu1804 from python .. it just freezes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found 2 ways to achieve this:

**A correct version of my code looks like this**

```
#e.g: To execute "ls -l"
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_call(['wsl', 'ls','-l','MaybeOtherParamHere']))
```

I should have used wsl to invoke linux shell from windows aka bash then my command and parameters in separated arguments for the subprocess command.

**The other way which I think is cleaner but may be heavier is using PowerShell Scripts:**

```
#script.ps1
param([String]$folderpath, [String]$otherparam)
Write-Output $folderpath
Write-Output $otherparam
wsl ls -l $folderpath $otherparam
```

Then to execute it in python and get the results:

```
import subprocess


def callps1():
    powerShellPath = r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
    powerShellCmd = "./script.ps1"
    #call script with argument '/mnt/c/Users/aaa/'
    p = subprocess.Popen([powerShellPath, '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', powerShellCmd, '/mnt/c/Users/aaa/', 'SecondArgValue']
                         , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = p.communicate()
    rc = p.returncode
    print("Return code given to Python script is: " + str(rc))
    print("\n\nstdout:\n\n" + str(output))
    print("\n\nstderr: " + str(error))


# Test
callps1()
```

Thank you for helping out

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
print(subprocess.check_call(['ubuntu1804', 'run', 'BashCmdHere(eg: ls)'])) #also try without "run" or change ubuntu1804 to wsl
```

Or

```
print(subprocess.check_call(['cmd', '/c', 'ubuntu1804', 'run', 'BashCmdHere(eg: ls)']))#also try without "run" or change "ubuntu1804" to "wsl"
# I think you need to play with quotes here to produce: cmd /c 'ubuntu1804 run BashCmdHere(eg: ls)'
```

First, try to call your command from `cmd.exe` to see the right format and then translate it to Python.

Comment: In your first suggestion, the cmd "run" turns to be unknown, additionally I found that I shall use "wsl" instead of "ubuntu1804" to invoke the Linux shell, ubuntu1804 considers everything after it as an argument instead of command 
However if I remove run and change ubuntu1804 to wsl, surprisingly it works so here is your up-vote.
Also, I've found another way to achieve my objective involving PowerShell scripts, I'm posting it bellow as well as the proper way I found to do it using whats above .. cheers

Answer (score -1):

```
os.system('bash')
```

I figured this out by accident.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked, which was how to execute a command *inside* WSL such as `ls` or a script and *"retrieve its results to python"*.  Also, note that the `bash.exe` command to launch WSL [has been deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#deprecated-wsl-commands).  You should use the replacement `wsl.exe` command.